# How do I add regression lines to scatterplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot

My data contains of measurements of different variables from 2 years.

I created a scatterplot with ggplot2, and coloured the points and regressions line by year using:

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=xdata, y=ydata, colour = Year))  +
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```

How do I add a third regression line ignoring the year-column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ggplot(mydata, aes(x=xdata, y=ydata))  +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour = Year), method = "lm") +
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")
```